# What is the most efficient method to return ranked modes from a list of integers in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, statistics

What is the most efficient method that, given as parameters a list of int `elems`:, and an int `k`, returns the k most frequent values in descending order by frequency. Without dropping into a lower level language.

```
def most_frequent(elems, k):
  # the code goes here
```

```
most_frequent([1,4,1,3,2,4,4], 2)
$> [4,1]
```

Comment: `Counter.most_common`?

Comment: Thanks Francisco, that works, but I am looking for the lower level algorithm behind the python method.

Comment: You can achieve this with `O(nk)`  time complexity, but `O(n)` space complexity. (Run on the list, append each frequency a dictionary) - then run `k` times on the dictionary to find the largest frequency, although when `k=n` it should be more useful to *sort* the dictionary first then pick the correct indexes (`O(nlg n)`)

Comment: Having spent only a few minutes thinking about it, it seems like O(n log n) is possible, right? Sort the array (n log n time), find indices of breakpoints between nonidentical elements (n time), compute number of identical elements as difference between indices found in step before (n time worst case), sort numbers of identical elements (n log n time worst case), look at last k elements. All this requires that elements be comparable, but OP said they're integers so that's okay.